# Intact printing of text on crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Mabuhay!

Is there a way I can format text(paragraph) on crystal reports with at least exact spacing on paragraph?

Sample:

Adress: abcdef, ghijkld, 
mnopherss 
dasdjassjdasddd, 
adsddddsdasdasdasd, fasdfasfsfasdf

I want every rows to be intact line spacing will be exact about .2 spacing after the other.

Thanks,

Comment: Address is a single database field or there are multiple database fields included in that?

Comment: hi @Siva its a single field. it can be multiple also. Everytime i adjust the font spacing and line spacing i cant make it with a little spaicng on every row. Is there a possible way for that or it is built in for crytals report? Or can form do that using labels?

Answer (score 0):

If address is multiple fields then you can break line after couple of fields like below:

Create a formula and write as below:

```
"Address:"& {Field1}&" , "&{Field2}&Chrw(13)&
{Field3}&" , "&{Field4}&Chrw(13)&
{Field5}&" , "&{Field6}
```

If address is a single field then you need to break the field into required number of characters..Lets take example of 10 characters

```
"Address:"& Left({Field},10)&" , "&MID({Field2},10,10)&Chrw(13)&
Right({Field4},10)&Chrw(13)
```

Above is just an example... you need to play a bit with these functions